# How to truncate number before decimal?

Tags: java, number-formatting

Below code truncate number after decimal

```
 NumberFormat blah= new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

But I want to truncate extra zeros from the number which are present before number

eg

```
0000000000000.00  -> 0.00
00000100000.00 -> 100000.00
000000175000.00 -> 175000.00
```

Comment: Do you have "0000000000000.00" as a string?

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("000000.00")`

Comment: Dou mean you want to parse those strings into floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigDecimal myNumber = new BigDecimal("00000000175000.000000");
BigDecimal truncatedNumber = myNumber.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the number format unless you want to print it out that way. Just take the string and use `Double.parseDouble()`, then print the format:

```
// "#.00" always shows 2 digits after decimal, "#.##" is optional if zeros are after decimal
NumberFormat blah = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

String s = "00000100000.00";
System.out.println(blah.format(Double.parseDouble(s)));
```

Comment: getting output as 100000.0 and not 100000.00

Comment: @Edward Then you want your DecimalFormat to be this: `"#.00"`, `#` is a "Digit, zero shows as absent" and `0` is just "Digit"